# emulating a shell and running a .sh file

Tags: c

I have to emulate a shell with the ability to run bash files, the shell needed to support !!, echo and exit, thus here is what I have done thus far:

```
void run_file(char* file){
    int i;
    char* echo = "echo";
    char* ex = "exit";
    char* prev_f = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_CMD_BUFFER);
    char* nline = "\n";
    char* bang = "!!";
    char check[5];
    char c_bang[3];
    char c_nline[2];
    
    c_nline[1] = '\0';
    FILE *fp = fopen(file, "r");
    char line[MAX_CMD_BUFFER];
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    while((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1){
        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            check[i] = line[i];
            if(i < 2){
                c_bang[i] = line[i];
            }
        }
        c_nline[0]=line[0];
        check[4] = '\0';
        c_bang[3] = '\0';
        if(strcmp(c_nline, nline) == 0){continue;}
        else if(strcmp(check, echo) == 0){
            i = 5;
            if (line[5] =='\n')
            {
                continue;
            }
            while(line[i] != '\n'){
                printf("%c", line[i]);
                i++;
            }
            strcpy(prev_f, line);
        }
        else if(strcmp(c_bang, bang) == 0){
            if(*prev_f == NULL){continue;}
            i = 0;
            for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
                check[i] = prev_f[i];
            }
            check[4] = '\0';
            if(strcmp(check, echo) == 0){
                i = 5;
                if (prev_f[5] == '\n'){
                    continue;
                }
                while(prev_f[i] != '\n'){
                    printf("%c", prev_f[i]);
                    i++;
                }
            }
            else if(strcmp(check, ex) == 0){
                char val[3];
                for(i = 5; i < 8; i++){
                    val[i - 5] = prev_f[i];
                }
                int v = atoi(val);
                if(v > 255){v = 255;}
                printf("bye!\n");
                exit(v);
            }
            else{
                printf("invalid previous command");
            }
        }
        else if(strcmp(check, ex) == 0){
            char val[3];
            for(i = 5; i < 8; i++){
                val[i - 5] = line[i];
            }
            int v = atoi(val);
            if(v > 255){v = 255;}
            printf("$ echo $?\n");
            printf("%d\n$", v);
            strcpy(prev_f, line);
            exit(v);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    free(prev_f);
}
```

However `getline()` doesn't store the data of the line correctly thus I cannot run the commands correctly. is there any way to overcome this or would I need to manually read the file to a buffer then see what command is in the buffer?
I don't know whats an easy alternative/fix

thank you

Comment: Why only "emulate" a shell? Why not build an actual shell? Because that's basically what you need to do anyway.

Comment: *However getline() doesn't store the data of the line correctly* - what does it mean?

Comment: By the way, `c_bang[3] = '\0';` will write out of bounds.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre]. Never describe a problem merely as “doesn't store the data of the line correctly.” Always describe precisely what behavior was observed and what behavior was desired instead. How can somebody else reproduce the problem? What data was stored? How do you know—how can somebody else see it? What data should have been stored instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem is that, for the `getline` call, you're not using an appropriate first parameter, or a correct value for the second parameter. As explained in the [getline() manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html),

> If *lineptr is set to NULL before the call, then getline() will allocate a buffer for storing the line.  This buffer should be freed by the user program even if getline() failed.
>
> Alternatively, before calling getline(), *lineptr can contain a pointer to a [malloc(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html)-allocated buffer *n bytes in size.  If the buffer is not large enough to hold the line, getline() resizes it with [realloc(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realloc.3.html), updating *lineptr and *n as necessary.
>
> In either case, on a successful call, *lineptr and *n will be updated to reflect the buffer address and allocated size respectively.

In particular, the function is expecting to either get a NULL pointer or a pointer to an `malloc` allocated buffer. However, you're instead passing it a pointer to a  buffer allocated on the stack. Thus, `getline` assumes that your `len` value is the size of the buffer. Since you have set it to 0, this means the buffer is not large enough so `getline` will need to reallocate the buffer and, as stated, it will update the value to reflect the buffer address. However, since this is not actually a variable, it won't not work properly. Thus, you need to at least initialize `len` to be `MAX_CMD_BUFFER`.

Note the "C For Dummies Blog" [The getline() Function](https://c-for-dummies.com/blog/?p=1112) page explains the appropriate way to use this function, e.g., with `malloc` for the line pointer. Nonetheless, to use a stack buffer as you do instead, it also shows how to do that later in the page, i.e., by using a character pointer to the buffer. Its example has these 2 lines

```c
   char buffer[32];
   char *b = buffer;
```

where `&b` is passed to `getline` instead of `&buffer`. Nonetheless, this will only work properly if the buffer size is always sufficient so `getline` doesn't need to try to do any reallocations. This is because, as explained in [realloc(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realloc.3.html),

> Unless `ptr` is NULL, it must have been returned by an earlier call to **malloc** or related functions.

In your case, we get UB (Undefined Behavior), where anything from it working properly, returning an error code or even causing a segmentation fault may occur. Nonetheless, assuming it works, then the remainder of your code should actually always use the character pointer, e.g., `b`, instead of `buffer`, unlike the "Dummies" page example which later has the line `printf("You typed: '%s'\n",buffer);` (also, in case `realloc` has been called and new memory allocated, when the code is finished using that buffer, it should also technically check if the value is different and, if so, call `free` on it).

As such, I suggest you don't use your approach, especially if you can't be certain that your buffer size will never be exceeded. Instead, you should use the recommended method of letting `getline` do the initial allocation for you, or using `malloc` yourself instead.

There are also several other issues with your code. For example, as mentioned in [Some programmer dude's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77969676/emulating-a-shell-and-running-a-sh-file/77969932#comment137456446_77969676), `c_bang[3] = '\0';` will write out bounds. In addition, to be more robust, you should add a few more checks regarding how much text is in the read buffer before doing certain operations with it.